# Unable to pass array by reference correctly

Tags: c++

I'm trying to add two rows of my array together in a function and its not doing it and I can't tell why its not as the code looks right and doesn't error out.  I have tried using a * and & to pass it by reference but I always get code errors.  Thanks

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void addRow(int arr[100][100], int firstrow,int secondrow,int rows, int cols);

void addRow(int arr[100][100], int firstrow,int secondrow,int rows, int cols){
    int i =0;
    int j = cols;
    while(i<rows){
        arr[secondrow][j]+=arr[firstrow][j];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    print(arr,rows,cols);
}
```

Comment: Arrays are always passed by reference.

Comment: what errors? compiler? runtime? gremlins?

Comment: @Wug More correctly, as a function parameter, an array type is converted to a pointer.  So his declaration `int arr[100][100]` becomes `int (*arr)[100]` (which will trigger an array to pointer conversion at the call site).

Comment: @JamesKanze: pointers and references are secretly the same thing.  SSSHHH DON'T TELL ANYONE

Comment: @JamesKanze but that's clearly not the issue here, it's the logic

Comment: @Wug Hardly.  Pointers are full bodied objects, which have their own address, and can be modified (if not const).  That's not the case for references.  (And even if you write your parameter `int arr[100][100]`, `++arr` is legal.

Comment: The machine code generated by use of pointers and references is identical except in cases where the pointer is modified; even then, it may be equivalent depending on how it's used and compiler optimizations.  References have their own addresses, you're just not allowed to take them, nor are you allowed to change what they point to.  It's possible to have a null reference, it's the same as having a null pointer (it blows up when you try to use it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array is passed correctly, it's your code that's not doing the additions right.

You set `j` to `cols` at the beginning, and move it in the increasing order with `j++`. As the result, all your accesses to array elements are past the end of the row. Loop exit condition is not right either, unless your matrices are always square (in which case there is no point to pass separate counts for rows and columns).

This should work:

```
void addRow(int arr[100][100], int firstrow,int secondrow,int rows, int cols){
    for(int j = 0 ; j != cols ; j++){
        arr[secondrow][j] += arr[firstrow][j];
    }
    print(arr, rows, cols);
}
```

Comment: Hmm. While working I don’t like this style of passing arrays. C++ shouldn’t even let this compile.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I do not like this style of passing arrays either. Moreover, I think there's no point in using C-style arrays in C++, given the `vector` and `array` containers of the standard C++ library.

Answer (score 3):

```
void addRow(int (&arr)[100][100], int firstrow,int secondrow,int rows, int cols);
```

would be the correct signature if you want to pass by reference.

```
template <typename std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols>
void addRow(int (&arr)[rows][cols], int firstrow,int secondrow);
```

then you won't even need rows & cols as parameters within the context of your program.

Comment: Then you don’t need `int rows, int cols` though.

Answer (score 2):

Change `arr[100][100]` to `arr[][100]`.  (Actually, several other changes, such as making the 100 a symbolic constant, would serve to improve the code's style, but this is the principal needed change.)

The reason is not trivial to understand, but important to C++ programming nonetheless.  What is actually passed to the function `addRow()` is -- please read the following carefully -- *the address of the first row of 100 ints.*  This address in turn is the address of the first int, but the passing semantics are as I said.  Thus, within `addRow()`, the symbol `arr` acts as a constant pointer to an array of 100 ints, not to an array of 10,000 ints.